# Sending bulk "Weekly Digest" email from Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail

I created a rake task to send emails to my subscribers (registered users).

digest.rake:

```
desc "Send digest"
task :send_digest => :environment do
   Notifier.digest.deliver #if Time.now.monday?
end
```

Notifier::digest

```
 def digest(periodicity = "weekly")

   @from = "biowatts@gmail.com"

   @bcc = ""
     User.where("digest_periodicity LIKE ?", periodicity).each do |u|
       @bcc += u.email_address + ","
     end
   @bcc = Rails.env.production? ? @bcc[0..-1] : "biowatts@gmail.com"

   @message_subject = Rails.env.production? ? "#{periodicity.capitalize} Digest" : "#{periodicity.capitalize} Digest (Test)"

   @public_projects = PowerPlant.where("public = ?", true).order("created_at desc")  

   mail(:bcc => @bcc, :subject => @message_subject)
```

end

This works all fine until I try to deploy.
On my production environment my list of recipients is over 300 emails addresses.
so when I run the proper rake command, instead of sending my email I am getting this message.

```
$ heroku rake send_digest --app biowatts
> rake aborted!
> 452-4.5.3 Your message has too many recipients. For more information regarding
```

I am using a smtp.gmail.com
but I also tried to use my godaddy smtp mail server, 
but it looks like I am going to face similar issues.

MY QUESTION: How do I send an email periodically to the list of my subscribers?

Note This email is build upon what's in my database ...

hope you can help,

joel

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you show us some code and give us some insight on what's not working?

Comment: You need to tell us what's going wrong or which bit you are having trouble with.  Is it the actual sending of emails, is it scheduling a job to run weekly, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the poor description of my problem. I must have been very tired. Thanks for pointing this out. I edited and added more information. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine. The issue is the rules for gmail. You can't send that many emails at once. If you have ever had a friend's account hacked you will see they send the email to 100 or so recipients and repeat.

Solution:
Have multiple emails and rotate (this is a bad idea because it will trigger other spam defenses from gmail)

Use Constant Contact or some other bulk mailer - Ideal for your situation

Use SendGrid - They will likely drop you as you are "spamming" in their eyes even though you aren't really spamming.